# Using `keyup` to Filter/Search from my `.json' file already displaying on my html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

I have been working on this for several days now and I'm not having much luck.
I have a json file `ReptilesTX.json` with several animals and I would like to have the option
search box [image]. Then, have the already loaded animals filtered out to only keep the ones matching the search.
Any guidance on how should I take this approach? Below is what I tried so far but I'm getting some errors I don't know how to read to troubleshoot. Thanks in advance for any tips/help.

[image]

Here is my html

```
 <div id="container">
        <form role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="input" class="form-control input-lg" id="txt-search" placeholder="Type your search character">
            </div>

          <p id="postAnimal">Posting goes here</p>
  

    </div>
```

Reduced example of my json file

```
[
  {
    "id": "americanalligator",
    "friendlyName": "American Alligator",
    "scientificName": "Alligator mississippiensis",
    "url": "https://tpwd.texas.gov/huntwild/wild/species/americanalligator/",
    "picturePath": "/assets/americanalligator",
    "description": "The American alligator is a large...",
    "lifeHistory": "An agile swimmer, the American alligator...",
    "habitat": "Alligators are found in or near water....",
    "distribution": "The American alligator is found ..."
  },
  {
    "id": "bullsnake",
    "friendlyName": "Bullsnake",
    "scientificName": "Pituophis catinefer sayi",
    "url": "https://tpwd.texas.gov/huntwild/wild/species/bullsnake/",
    "picturePath": "/assets/bullsnake",
    "description": "The bullsnake is a heavy-bodied snake...",
    "lifeHistory": "Bullsnakes vary in temperament... ",
    "habitat": "Bullsnakes prefer sandy soils in fields...",
    "distribution": "Bullsnakes occur in the western..."

  }
  ]
```

My javascript

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
const Reptiles = "ReptilesTX.json";

xhr.onload = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

    let output = '';
    for(let i = 0; i < response.length; i++){

        output +=  `
    <ul id="list">
        <li id="name">${response[i].friendlyName}</li><br>
        <li><img src='${response[i].picturePath}.jpg'</li><br>
        <li><span>Scientific Name: </span>${response[i].scientificName}</li>
        <li><span>Description: </span>${response[i].description}</li><br>
        <li><span>Life History: </span>${response[i].lifeHistory}</li><br>
        <li><span>Habitat: </span>${response[i].habitat}</li><br>
        <li><span>Distribution: </span>${response[i].distribution}</li>
        <li><span>Source: </span><a href="${response[i].url}">Site</a></li>
    </ul>;
    `
    }
    //console.log(output)
    document.getElementById("postAnimal").innerHTML = output;
    } 
};
xhr.open("GET", Reptiles, true);
xhr.send();



$('#txt-search').keyup(function(){
    var searchField = $(this).val();
    if(searchField === '')  {
        $('#filter-records').html('');
        return;
    }
    
    var regex = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
    var output = '<div class="row">';
    var count = 1;
      $.each(Reptiles, function(key, val){
        if ((val.friendlyName.search(regex) != -1) || (val.scientificName.search(regex) != -1)) {output = `
        <ul id="list">
            <li id="name">${response.friendlyName}</li><br>
            <li><img src='${response.picturePath}.jpg'</li><br>
            <li><span>Scientific Name: </span>${response.scientificName}</li>
            <li><span>Description: </span>${response.description}</li><br>
            <li><span>Life History: </span>${response.lifeHistory}</li><br>
            <li><span>Habitat: </span>${response.habitat}</li><br>
            <li><span>Distribution: </span>${response.distribution}</li>
            <li><span>Source: </span><a href="${response.url}">Site</a></li>
        </ul>;
        `
          if(count%2 == 0){
            output += '</div><div class="row">'
          }
          count++;
        }
      });
      output += '</div>';
      $('#filter-records').html(output);
});
```

[image]

Comment: Another approach would be to filter the HTML that's already on the page. With each keystroke you could search for `<li>`s or `id`s or names or whatever you want and show or hide the elements that match. Since you have access to the HTML that creates the page, you can add custom attributes that make it easy to search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work with some help.

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
const Reptiles = "ReptilesTX.json";

var dataFromServer = [];

xhr.onload = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    dataFromServer = response;
    let output = '';
    for(let i = 0; i < response.length; i++){

        output +=  `
    <ul id="list">
        <li id="name">${response[i].friendlyName}</li><br>
        <li><img src='${response[i].picturePath}.jpg'</li><br>
        <li><span>Scientific Name: </span>${response[i].scientificName}</li>
        <li><span>Description: </span>${response[i].description}</li><br>
        <li><span>Life History: </span>${response[i].lifeHistory}</li><br>
        <li><span>Habitat: </span>${response[i].habitat}</li><br>
        <li><span>Distribution: </span>${response[i].distribution}</li>
        <li><span>Source: </span><a href="${response[i].url}">Site</a></li>
    </ul>;
    `
    }
    //console.log(output)
    document.getElementById("postAnimal").innerHTML = output;
    } 
};
xhr.open("GET", Reptiles, true);
xhr.send();



$('#txt-search').keyup(function(){
    var searchField = $(this).val();
    if(searchField === '')  {
        $('#filter-records').html('');
        return;
    }
    
    var regex = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
    var output = '<div class="row">';
    var count = 1;
    console.log({dataFromServer})
      $.each(dataFromServer, function(key, val){
          console.log({key, val})
        if ((val.friendlyName.search(regex) != -1) || (val.scientificName.search(regex) != -1)) {output = `
        <ul id="list">
            <li id="name">${val.friendlyName}</li><br>
            <li><img src='${val.picturePath}.jpg'</li><br>
            <li><span>Scientific Name: </span>${val.scientificName}</li>
            <li><span>Description: </span>${val.description}</li><br>
            <li><span>Life History: </span>${val.lifeHistory}</li><br>
            <li><span>Habitat: </span>${val.habitat}</li><br>
            <li><span>Distribution: </span>${val.distribution}</li>
            <li><span>Source: </span><a href="${val.url}">Site</a></li>
        </ul>;
        `
          if(count%2 == 0){
            output += '</div><div class="row">'
          }
          count++;
        }
      });
      output += '</div>';
      $('#postAnimal').html(output);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic search that shows and hides HTML. Right now it shows/hides list items, but you could wrap each animal in a div with an id and search for that.

Also, this only searches for entire words but you could adjust it to search for each letter and hide more and more animals as the search gets more specific.

```js
function doFilter() {

  var searchInput = document.getElementById("searchInput").value;

  $("li").filter("li[data-" + searchInput + "]")
    .css("display", "block");

  $("li").not("li[data-" + searchInput + "]")
    .css("display", "none");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Enter one of the animals on the list, without 'data-'.<br />
The whole word must be entered.<br /><br />

<input id="searchInput" type="text" onkeyup="doFilter()" />

<ul>
  <li data-aardvark>aardvarks eat ants...</li>
  <li data-kangaroo>what's that kangaroo doing here?</li>
  <li data-lizard>lizards are cold...</li>
  <li data-alligator>gators play football...</li>
</ul>
```